# Excel VBA - variable for loop

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I can't seem to get my second for loop right. I'm looking for the cell with value 'Persoonlijke prijslijst'. Once I have this cell I need to go up two and delete 8 down. When I debug, it says temp = 0 so I presume it's in my second for loop.

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 800
    Range("C" & i).Select
    If Range("C" & i).Value = "Persoonlijke prijslijst" Then
        Dim temp As Integer
        For temp = i - 2 To temp + 8
            Range("C" & temp).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        Next temp
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Do you mean go up two rows and then delete 8 rows down from there?

Comment: It's because you're deleting rows within that second for loop. Every time a row is deleted, the temp variable would also need to be updated. But it's better to do it Kyle's way.

Comment: It's the thought that counts :)

Comment: How come one can have incorrect thoughts ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim StrSearch As String
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet name        
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    StrSearch = "Persoonlijke prijslijst"

    With ws
        For i = 800 To 1 Step -1
            If .Range("C" & i).Value = StrSearch Then
                .Rows(i - 2 & ":" & i + 5).Delete
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @mattboy: It's not about points. I never care for that ;) So you may reverse the vote that you gave. It about doing something right ;)

Comment: @Siddhart: Nah you still deserve it. Yours probably actually works!

Answer (score 5):

Another way without looping 800 times:

```
 Sub testing()

Dim rng As Range
Dim fAddress As String
Dim rngRows As Range

With Sheet1.Range("C1:C800")
    Set rng = .Find("Persoonlijke prijslijst")
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        fAddress = rng.Address
        Do
        If rngRows Is Nothing Then
            Set rngRows = rows(rng.Row - 2 & ":" & rng.Row + 5)
        Else
            Set rngRows = Union(rngRows, rows(rng.Row - 2 & ":" & rng.Row + 5))
        End If
           Set rng = .FindNext(rng)
        Loop While Not rng Is Nothing And rng.Address <> fAddress
    End If
End With

rngRows.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this work for multiple selections? So if Persoonlijke prijslijst is in my document 4 times?

Comment: @Tom, I have covered about .Find and .FindNext in this link. "http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/" For such small number of rows, you can use looping. However if you use `.Find` you have to be very careful as if you delete the range then `Set rng = .FindNext(rng)` line will give you the error ;) Let me know if you want a `.Find` code as well :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, so using .find and .findnext is less CPU intensive? I haven't used this function in the past, so I'm quite interested. If you have time and don't mind, I would say yes to a .find version :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout is quite right, I hadn't tested it. I've updated my original code :S Thanks Sid

Comment: @Tom, Find is fast, but it also requires less looping, you should try and avoid looping in VBA since it is slow. Calling the worksheet (doing things with it) is also slow so should be done as little as possible or all in one go if you can

Comment: @SiddharthRout, in that case I can't spot the issue, it works as I would expect it to? So I'm afraid you're going to have to tell me what I'm missing ;)

Comment: @Kyle: Seems like I still had your old code which was giving me incorrect results. Yes this one now works :) The emphasis was on setting `rngRows` +1 for providing a code that works:)

Comment: @Tom: You didn't have to unselect Kyles answer. You may now select his answer since he has amended the code and it works :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks Sid, had me questioning my sanity for a bit there ;)

Comment: @Kyle: I am the biggest fan of .FIND and .FINDNEXT (as you can see it in my blog (http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) but It is not feasible for such small rows. You end up writing more code :)

Comment: Pardon me for the mistake, I wanted to accept Sids answer, because his worked first :) I thought I had accepted his, but due to stackoverflow crashing for me, something went wrong.

Comment: @Tom: I thought it was just me. SO is crashing on me as well.